# FlatMap in Java with Spark 2.1.0

Tags: java, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am trying to flatMap with with spark 2.1.0 from Java 8

The 2.2.0 docs show this example

```
JavaDStream<String> words = lines.flatMap(x -> Arrays.asList(x.split(" ")).iterator());
```

When I try that from 2.1.0 I get the following

```
Error:(31, 25) java: method flatMap in class org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD<T> cannot be applied to given types;
required: scala.Function1<java.lang.String,scala.collection.TraversableOnce<U>>,scala.reflect.ClassTag<U>
found: (x)->Array[...]tor()
reason: cannot infer type-variable(s) U
(actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
```

What is the correct way to flatMap given these versions?

Answer (score 0):

Below code works fine for Spark 2.1.0.

```
JavaDStream<String> lines = messages.map(tuple -> tuple._2());
JavaDStream<String> words = lines.flatMap(x -> Arrays.asList(SPACE.split(x)).iterator());
JavaPairDStream<String, Integer> wordCounts = words.mapToPair(s -> new Tuple2<>(s, 1))
    .reduceByKey((i1, i2) -> i1 + i2);
```

Please check you `pom.xml` for spark dependencies version. If you want to refer Spark 2.1.0 version of examples please go to https://github.com/apache/spark/tree/branch-2.1/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/spark/examples/streaming